# Existence of a homeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}$ with certain properties

Tags: general-topology

> Let $p,q \in \mathbb{R}$ with $p \neq q$. Then there exists a homeomorphism $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $h(p) = q$ which is the identity mapping on $\mathbb{R}$ except a bounded set containing $p$ and $q$.

First of all, $h(q) \neq q$ since $h$ should be a homeomorphism. But somehow, I do not get the right idea by dwaing some graphs. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: An example with $p>q$; in this case the bounded interval is $[0,c]$.

[image]

Comment: Ah I see. I was dealing with the case $q > p$ but I think it goes the same way as your solution, I might put $c$ between $p$ and $q$, right? Thanks.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek: If $q>p$ you’ll still have $c$ to the right of both $p$ and $q$, but the bump will be above the diagonal instead of below it.

Comment: That was dumb, sorry.

Comment: @satish: I could take a quick look now.

Comment: The solution is posted as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585651/find-the-distribution-of-the-sum-z-x-1x-2-x-n/1586801#1586801.  I gave a different solution than what the book's author has given.  Was not quite sure if it is right, seems correct for me.  Hopefully you can tell me

Comment: @satish: I’ll take another look after I get some sleep, but at the moment I don’t follow some of your reasoning. Also, your last two displayed formulas are inconsistent: it can’t be true that $P(Z)=1$ *and* $P(Z)=\frac1{2-p}$ unless $p=1$.

Comment: Thanks, Dr Scott I would correct that now and you can take a look tomorrow whenever you have time